# C# Regex extract content of a div

Tags: c#, regex

I've seen some related questions of mine, and I tried them but they don't work.
I want to match the content from a div with the id "thumbs". But the regex.Success returns false :(

```
Match regex = Regex.Match(html, @"<div[^>]*id=""thumbs"">(.+?)</div>");
```

Comment: Partially off topic but sounds like a candidate for the HTML Agility Pack

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Regex is not a good choice for parsing HTML files..

HTML is not strict nor is it regular with its format..

Use [htmlagilitypack](http://html-agility-pack.net/?z=codeplex)

---

Why use parser?

Consider your regex..There are infinite number of cases where you could break your code

- Your regex won't work if there are **nested** divs
- Some divs dont have an **ending tag**!(except XHTML)

---

You can use this code to retrieve it using `HtmlAgilityPack`

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.Load(yourStream);

var itemList = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@id='thumbs']")//this xpath selects all div with thubs id
                  .Select(p => p.InnerText)
                  .ToList();

//itemList now contain all the div tags content having its id as thumbs
```

Comment: Loving the comment on *irregular* expressions :)

Comment: "Irregular expression" is not a joke... HTML is, literally, an irregular language!!

Comment: @TomLord indeed..it is irregular to the core...:)

Answer (score 1):

No I dont think he needs escapes. He has @ in front of pattern. I think this is correct:

```
<div[^>]*id="thumbs">(.+?)</div>
```

So no double double quotes

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Regex r = new Regex(@"(?<text>(<div\s*?id=(\""|&quot;|&\#34;)"
    + @"thumb(\""|&quot;|&\#34;).*?>)(?>.*?</div>|.*?<div "
    + @"(?>depth)|.*?</div> (?>-depth))*)(?(depth)(?!)).*?</div>",
    RegexOptions.Singleline);
```